# python: how to find \r\n\r\n in one single search

Tags: python, regex, string

I have to split the file content based on **first** occurrence of `\r\n\r\n`

I need flexibility such a way that the lines can just ends with `\r\n\r\n` or `\n\n`.

How to split the text?

Example added:

```
\===================FILE BEGIN==========================================
name: about

title: About

publish: True

order: -1

\r\n

\r\n


**example.com** is a example website provides the latest examples in organized way. 

Blah blah blah....
Blah blah blah....
Blah blah blah....
\===================File END==========================================
```

First portion is my header(in yaml format) used for file identity and second portion is markdown text.

Comment: Can you show some example of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

linend = re.compile(r'\r\n\r\n|\n\n')
s = 'an example\n\nstring\n\nhere'
print linend.split(s, 1)
s = 'another\r\n\r\nexample\r\n\r\nhere'
print linend.split(s, 1)
```

prints:

```
['an example', 'string\n\nhere']
['another', 'example\r\n\r\nhere']
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern `"\r\n\r\n|\n\n"` should work. Simply use `re.split` or `Regex.split` and set `maxsplit=1`.